# How to use openquery for inserting geometry data from my server into linked server

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

I am trying to use a query modified from MS docs to insert GEOMETRY data from my sql server into a linked sql server (Azure).

openquery for select works fine with the client's choice of naming for their db which includes '-' ([their-db-name]).

```
SELECT * FROM openquery([LINKED SERVER],
   'SELECT [geometry] FROM [their-db-name].[theirSchema].[Dimensions]');

** correct result set returned **
```

However when I try INSERT I get:

```
INSERT openquery([LINKED SERVER],
    'SELECT [geometry] FROM [their-db-name].[theirSchema].[Dimensions]')
SELECT [geometry] FROM [my_db].[dbo].[Dimensions];

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 27
Incorrect syntax near '-'.
```

I don't have any control over their use of '-' in naming, however since the name is enclosed in '[]', and the openquery SELECT statement works fine I have exhausted all the syntax errors I can think of. 
Using 'INSERT INTO' makes no difference.

How can I make an insert work?
Thanks in advance!